# How to BeautifulSoup getting value that following div class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, request, find

I'm trying to extract the " 24.8 " from the following HTML code:

```
<div class="anlik-sicaklik">
   <div class="anlik-sicaklik-deger ng-binding" ng-bind="sondurum[0].sicaklik | comma">        
    24,8      
    ::after
    </div>
      <div class="anlik-sicaklik-havadurumu">

      <div class="anlik-sicaklik-havadurumu-ikonu">
```

Here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://mgm.gov.tr/tahmin/il-ve-ilceler.aspx?il=ANTALYA&ilce=KUMLUCA")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
sicaklik = soup.find('div', {'class':'anlik-sicaklik-deger'})
print(sicaklik)
```

My code's output

```
<div class="anlik-sicaklik-deger" ng-bind="sondurum[0].sicaklik | comma">
</div>
```

could you please help me to get **24,8** value?

Comment: This isn't really a beautifulsoup problem. Your desired value is generated dynamically by javascript, so you can't see it with `requests` as you might notice by examining `r.content`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question concern more about parsing string than web-page. So it is better, once found the tag with bs4, to parse the string with some regex.
The matching condition `([0-9]+,[0-9])` is one or more number separated by a `,` and then **a** number again.

**Notice** the the final result, `nr`, is a string, to make it a number you should use `float(nr.replace(',', '.'))`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
   <div class="anlik-sicaklik-deger ng-binding" ng-bind="sondurum[0].sicaklik | comma">        
    24,8      
    ::after
    </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

div = soup.find('div', class_='anlik-sicaklik-deger', string=True)
# get text
text = str(div.string).strip()
# regex
nr = re.search(r'([0-9]+,[0-9])', text).group(0)

print(nr)
```

Output

```
24,8
```

Comment: question not well posed. As required I scraped the given string snapshot and not the web-page

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

sicaklik = soup.find('div', {'class':'anlik-sicaklik-deger'}).**text**
```